# Inellij Show intention actions stopped working in Flutter

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

After upgrade to MacOS Catalina (or maybe unrelated) show intent actions command stopped working in Flutter.

If I run some error - show intent action is working just fine. https://take.ms/Jr7VY
If I just try to show intent actions for regular Widget - it isn't showing anything. In the past it was suggesting something like "Center Widget", "Add Widget", "Add Padding" and so on..

**UPD**: Updating to Android Studio 3.6 preview helped the problem (I didn't move any profiles). But still no idea what lead to the problem and how to fix on 3.5 stable.

Comment: 3.6 solved it for me also

Answer (score 1):

Does visual studio code works fine with showing intent action?

Maybe you should run `fluter doctor` to find if there are any issues with the flutter installation.

Also you can find more details in the official wiki on Catalina Support:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/State-of-Catalina-Support

Comment: Thank you Kevin, didn't find any issues on Catalina-Support. So as didn't find any issues with Flutter doctor.
So posted question in github. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42419

Answer (score 0):

Are IntelliJ plugins up to date? Especially flutter and dart? After reset all settings IntelliJ, reinstall plugins again its not flutter side problem, I think it’s IntelliJ problem

Comment: I also think it's IntelliJ problem. Reinstalling plugins and resetting setting should have had same effect as using clean Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to Android Studio 3.6 (currently in RC1 Preview).

You might want to check the Keymap. 
I found that in 3.6 with the default Keymap option-return worked but when I switched to Eclipse (macOs) Keymap, it stopped working again.
Search for "intention". When using the Eclipse (macOS) Keymap I found that the intentions command was not setup to use option-return so I added it and it works.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to download another Android Studio version (doesn't matter which) and install it. Helped two times.